# jQuery : fadeIn image when attribute change has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched through many questions here but i still didnt find the right solution.

I have a code which changes the image `src` attribute on click. What i need is to show the loader while changed source is loading, and when it does load, i want image to fadeIn. Is that possible?

**What i tried:**

```
$('#loader').show();

var link='http://www.linktoimage.com/image.jpg';

$('#button').on('click',function(){

    $("#img").attr('src', link).load(function() {

        $(this).fadeIn(300);
        $('#loader').hide();

    });

});
```

This is of course not working. If you know of any elegant solutions please do tell.

Comment: Couple of questions about your code: Why is `#loader` being hidden once the image is loaded? Also, is `link` a variable that isn't shown in the code you provided? the second argument of `.attr` should be a string, i.e. in quotes.

Comment: I edited my answer. Loader is hidden because it represents the spinning loader gif which dissapears after image is loaded. Anyways this is just an idea i was playing around with. Its not working though.

Comment: Shouldn't you bind the `load` handler *before* you initiate the load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hide the img element first, you can achieve the desired effect:

Take a look at this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/enrique_alcantara/zXbW3/

```
<button id="button">Cargar</button>
<img id="loader" src="http://www.deadmau5.com/wp-content/themes/deadmau5/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="50" height="50" />
<img id="img" />
```

JS

```
var link='http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11111/111117347/3150345-8768287685-the-av.jpeg';

$('#button').on('click',function(){

    $("#img").css('display', 'none').load(function() {
        $("#img").fadeIn(300);
        $('#loader').hide();

    }).attr('src', link);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an on load listener that will fade in the image and hide the loading message/image.

We also add a on click listener that will fade the current image out, show the loading message/image and change the image source.

**HTML**

```
<button id="Button">Change image</button>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/100/" alt="" id="Image" />
<div id="Loader">Loading...</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#Image').on('load', function() {
    $('#Loader').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('#Image').fadeIn(200);
    });
});
$('#Button').on('click', function() {
    $('#Image').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $('#Loader').show();
    });
    $('#Image').attr('src', 'http://lorempixel.com/200/100/');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZLMS/4/)**